# Why is a button with an image in it making the titleLable text cut off?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have this code below which creates a button in code and centers the button in the middle of its superview:

```
let cameraButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "cam"), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Take Pic", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return button
}()

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        view.addSubview(cameraButton)
        cameraButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cameraButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Everything is working fine (as in the button is being centered in the center of the view) but the titleLabel text is being cut off for some reason (shown in the picture below):

[image]

I thought buttons have an intrinsic width and height so why would the titleLabel be cut off here? Shouldn't the width just expand based on the content inside of it (the imageView as well as the label)? Can someone advise me a way to fix this?

Comment: or you can set font size if you don't want to change button frames.

Comment: So I have specify a width and height for the button?

Comment: pls try cameraButton.sizeToFit() after giving its image and text

Comment: I added `cameraButton.sizeToFit()` after `view.addSubview(cameraButton)` but that didn't solve it either.

Comment: you have to adjust button width, title insets and image insets from storyboard or programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with setting below attributes

```
        cameraButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        cameraButton.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cameraButton.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
```

Comment: I only used `cameraButton.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`. I wanted everything on the same line so I didn't use the `numberOfLines = 0` and default is already 1.

Comment: Helps a lot. Thank you! I also wanted to be the text on the same line, so I only used `cameraButton.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`